# What happens when mongoDB is shut down?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to Node and MongoDB and recently began using the database for my project. When I shut down the server with the following commands

- use admin
- db.shutdownServer()

and then again restart the server with the mongod command I find the databases I have created to be deleted. Why does this happen? What is the way to store the databases permanently?

Comment: Stupid question: do you use [In-Memory](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/index.html) database?

Comment: I don’t think @WernfriedDomscheit was saying your question is stupid; instead, they were just asking you, *Are you using the https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/ In-Memory Storage Engine?* And I guess they meant *their* question to you about that was maybe an obvious question ask (or something…)